# Javascript tooltip in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to add a tooltip with changing content for every field for asp.net web controls.

i want to use javascript or Jquery.

But i dnt want any libraries or plugins.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: example? demo? code? any details.

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="txtFeedName" runat="server" ToolTip="Short Name for the feed" onMouseDown="DisableRightClick(event)"></asp:TextBox>

Comment: this ia a text box. instead of using the attribute tooltip, I want something that would last till the mouse is over the textbox control

Comment: Edit ur qus would be preffered insted of adding code in comment

Answer (score 0):

In Asp controls have `ToolTip` attribute which shows tooltip, you need to set it according to your scenerio.

```
$("#<%=Controlid.ClientID%>").attr("ToolTip","Name");// in Jquery set ToolTip attribute
```

Comment: function DisplayInformation() {
            $("#<%=txtLoadCode.ClientID%>").attr("ToolTip", "Name"); // 
        }

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using jquery library then just add **jquery-ui.js** and **jquery-ui.css**.
Hence, you can use jquery tooltip feature; http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/.

**See examples:**

```
<p><a href="#" title="This is a example">Tooltips</a> Jquery Tooltip.</p>

$( document ).tooltip();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/jLkcs/5/

http://jsfiddle.net/tj_vantoll/kyBwU/

Comment: I have added these two libraries<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="Scripts/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Comment: which version of jquery? Please use all latest version http://jqueryui.com/download/.